# CMake is not finding Boost

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cgal

I am trying to install CGAL. They describe their installation process as ever-so-simple [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/installation_manual/Chapter_installation_manual.html#Subsection_6.1), section 6.1. When I run `cmake-gui` and then click `configure`, I get the following output:

```
CMake Error at D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1192 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.51.0

  Boost include path: D:/program files/boost_1_51

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_thread
          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:6 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:590 (include)
```

But I *did* set up `BOOST_ROOT`, in CMake's GUI, to `D:/program files/boost_1_51`, which exists. And the two libraries it mentions are definitely installed.  What is happening here? What do I need to do?

Attached is the output when running `cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON`:

```
D:\program files\CGAL-4.1>cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON
== Setting paths ==
-- Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.1
-- Packagenames: CGAL-4.1
== Setting paths (DONE) ==

== Generate version files ==
-- CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=4
-- CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=1
-- CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=0
-- CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=10
-- CGAL_SOVERSION     =10.0.0
-- CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
-- Building shared libraries
-- Targetting Visual Studio 10 Win64
-- Target build enviroment supports auto-linking
-- Using VC10 compiler.
-- Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)
-- USING CMake version: 2.8.10
-- System: Windows
== Generate version files (DONE) ==

== Set up flags ==
-- Build type: Release
-- USING CXXFLAGS = ' /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /Zm1000 /GR /EHsc -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_
DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_
WARNINGS /fp:strict /fp:except- /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG'
-- USING LDFLAGS = ' /STACK:10000000 /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO'
== Set up flags (DONE) ==

== Detect external libraries ==
-- External libraries supported: GMP;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;TA
UCS;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;Coin3D;NTL;IPE
-- Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
-- GMP has been preconfigured:
--   CGAL_UseGMP-file:
--   GMP include:      D:/program files/CGAL-4.1/auxiliary/gmp/include
--   GMP libraries:    D:/program files/CGAL-4.1/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.lib

--   GMP definitions:
-- USING GMP_VERSION = '5.0.1'
-- Preconfiguring library: MPFR ...
-- MPFR has been preconfigured:
--   CGAL_UseMPFR-file:
--   MPFR include:      D:/program files/CGAL-4.1/auxiliary/gmp/include
--   MPFR libraries:    D:/program files/CGAL-4.1/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.li
b
--   MPFR definitions:
-- USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.0.0'
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:566 ] _b
oost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.1;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.1;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.1;1.54.0;1.54;1.
53.1;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.1;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.1;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.1;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.1
;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.1;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.1;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.1;1.4
5.0;1.45;1.44.1;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.1;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.1;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.1;1.41.0;
1.41;1.40.1;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.1;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.1;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.1;1.37.0;1.37
;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;
1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1
.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37
.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:568 ] Bo
ost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:570 ] Bo
ost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = OFF
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:572 ] Bo
ost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME =
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:574 ] Bo
ost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 1.56.1;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.1;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.1;1.54.0;1.
54;1.53.1;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.1;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.1;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.1;1.50.0;1.50;1
.49.1;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.1;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.1;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.
1;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.1;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.1;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.1;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.1;1.
41.0;1.41;1.40.1;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.1;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.1;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.1;1.37.0
;1.37
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:576 ] Bo
ost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS =
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:644 ] De
clared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:646 ]
BOOST_ROOT = D:/program files/boost_1_51/bin
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:648 ]
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR =
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:650 ]
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR =
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:652 ] _b
oost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.1;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.1;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.1;1.54.0;1.54;1.
53.1;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.1;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.1;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.1;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.1
;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.1;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.1;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.1;1.4
5.0;1.45;1.44.1;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.1;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.1;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.1;1.41.0;
1.41;1.40.1;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.1;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.1;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.1;1.37.0;1.37
;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;
1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1
.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37
.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:734 ] lo
cation of version.hpp: D:/program files/boost_1_51/boost/version.hpp
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:754 ] ve
rsion.hpp reveals boost 1.51.0
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:786 ] gu
essed _boost_COMPILER = -vc100
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:796 ] _b
oost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:839 ] _b
oost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:841 ] _b
oost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:884 ] _b
oost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = D:/program files/boost_1_51/bin/lib;D:/program files/
boost_1_51/bin/stage/lib;D:/program files/boost_1_51/lib;D:/program files/boost_
1_51/../lib;D:/program files/boost_1_51/stage/lib;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;C:\Progr
am Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_51_0/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_51/li
b;C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/lib;C:\Program Files (x86)/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:962 ] Se
arching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_51;boost_thread-vc10
0-mt;boost_thread-mt-1_51;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:994 ] Se
arching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_51;boost_thread-vc1
00-mt-gd;boost_thread-mt-gd-1_51;boost_thread-mt-gd;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread

-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:962 ] Se
arching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-vc100-mt-1_51;boost_system-vc10
0-mt;boost_system-mt-1_51;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:994 ] Se
arching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_51;boost_system-vc1
00-mt-gd;boost_system-mt-gd-1_51;boost_system-mt-gd;boost_system-mt;boost_system

-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1108 ] B
oost_FOUND = FALSE
CMake Error at D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmak
e:1192 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.51.0

  Boost include path: D:/program files/boost_1_51

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_thread
          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:6 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:590 (include)


-- Boost include:     D:/program files/boost_1_51
-- Boost libraries:
-- Boost definitions:
-- USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.51.0'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==

== Write compiler_config.h ==
== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==

== Generating build files ==
Configuring libCGAL
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL is configured
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'Core' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Core
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Core is configured
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'ImageIO' detected
Configuring libCGAL_ImageIO
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- OpenGL include:
-- OpenGL libraries:   glu32;opengl32
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_ImageIO is configured
-- NOTICE: CGAL_ImageIO needs ZLib to read compressed files. That feature will n
ot be activated.
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'Qt3' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Qt3
-- CGAL_Qt3 needs Qt3, cannot be configured.
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'Qt4' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Qt4
-- USING OPENGL_VERSION = '1.1'
-- USING QT4_VERSION = '4.8.3'
-- OpenGL include:
-- OpenGL libraries:   glu32;opengl32
-- OpenGL definitions:
-- Qt4 include:        D:/QT/include
-- Qt4 libraries:      optimized;D:/QT/lib/qtmain.lib;debug;D:/QT/lib/qtmaind.li
b;optimized;D:/QT/lib/QtOpenGL4.lib;debug;D:/QT/lib/QtOpenGLd4.lib;optimized;D:/
QT/lib/QtGui4.lib;debug;D:/QT/lib/QtGuid4.lib;optimized;D:/QT/lib/QtCore4.lib;de
bug;D:/QT/lib/QtCored4.lib
-- Qt4 definitions:    -DQT_DLL
-- moc executable:     D:/QT/bin/moc.exe
-- uic executable:     D:/QT/bin/uic.exe
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Qt4 is configured
-- Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL;Core;ImageIO;Qt3;Qt4' detected
== Generating build files (DONE) ==

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

<sub>(I saw at least three questions with the same title as this question. Each of them had a different answer that worked for the OP, but not for me, so I am sorry to repeat the question...)</sub>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your output shows that CMake is searching for the libraries in the following places:

```
D:/program files/boost_1_51/bin/lib
D:/program files/boost_1_51/bin/stage/lib
D:/program files/boost_1_51/lib
D:/program files/boost_1_51/../lib
D:/program files/boost_1_51/stage/lib
C:/boost/lib
C:/boost
C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_51_0/lib
C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_51/lib
C:\Program Files (x86)/boost/lib
C:\Program Files (x86)/boost
/sw/local/lib
```

It also shows that it's expecting the libraries to be named in a certain way. For example, the release version of Boost.Thread:

```
boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_51
boost_thread-vc100-mt
boost_thread-mt-1_51
boost_thread-mt
boost_thread
```

If your Boost libraries do exist in one of the searched locations, then it's probably the name of the library that's the problem. You can adjust the expected name of the Boost libraries by setting the appropriate CMake variables relevant to the [FindBoost module](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module:FindBoost).

For example, if you built Boost using bjam with `link=static threading=multi` then in your CMakeLists.txt before `find_package(Boost ...)` you'll want to do

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
```

Or invoke CMake with `-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBoost_USE_MULTITHREADED=ON`.

As @noam has pointed out in the comments below, in this particular case, it appears that CGAL requires the shared (DLL) versions of the Boost libraries; passing `-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON` on the command line doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I am using a university computer which already has boost on it. How can I know how did they compile boost (I really have no one to ask :) )

Comment: @noam It can usually be deduced from the libraries' names.  What is the full name and path of say the debug and release versions of Boost.Thread there?

Comment: I hope I understand you correctly: `libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib` and `libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_51.lib`

Comment: @noam OK - the libraries are static (you can tell because they begin with "lib" - see Boost's [getting started guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming)) so you need `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` set to `ON`.  In your output above, you can see that you currently have this value set to `OFF`.  Once you do that, assuming the libs are actually in one of the search paths listed in my answer, it should all work.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. The libs are in `D:\program files\boost_1_51\lib`, but it still outputs the same error, when running `cmake -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON`. (Thank you for your patience, by the way)

Comment: @noam If you run cmake with `-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBoost_DEBUG=ON` does the output still show `-- [ D:/program files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:570 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = OFF`?  If so, then your command line value for `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` is being overridden in CGAL's CMakeLists.txt.  This means you either have to change the entry in the CMakeLists.txt to `ON` or build a separate copy of boost using `link=shared` to generate the libs expected by CGAL.

Comment: I think I rather not mess with the makefile so as to not break any assumptions they make. I can try to download and install the correct libs (I am not much of a c programmer myself so I don't plan to compile them). I can download from boostpro, but which lib is the correct one? DLL, static, or the third option that has no lib description?

Comment: @noam I would think the DLL versions would be the ones.  You could try them all - the `FindBoost` module *should* find the appropriate ones.

Comment: Thanks - that worked for me. I accepted your answer - perhaps also add the suggestion to install the DLL's as pat of the answer?

Comment: CGAL uses a special variable to use static Boost libraries. It `CGAL_Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`. This should be fixed.

Answer (score 9):

I had this error, but I have progressed.

I was using the CMake GUI, ticked the checkbox "Advanced" (between checkbox "Grouped" and button "Add Entry"), and ticked the newly seen checkbox "CGAL_Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS".

You may need to press "Configure" an extra time or two before the extra options are revealed.

Answer (score 2):

Today I tried installing CGAL with Boost 1.57 x64 on Windows and encountered the same problem. I installed Boost via pre-build binaries and the .lib files that CMake searches for are in the `lib64-msvc-12.0` folder.

Therefore adding `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=.../boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-12.0` to CMake options was the solution for me.

Comment: Thanks, same here with boost 1.60 x64 binary install on Windows 7 and CGAL 1.47. I added `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\boost\lib64-msvc-14.0` in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Your system (through CMake) is not able to find Boost complied static libraries (.a files). So try to include the path in the CMake file where the .a files exist in your system. For example,

```
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR {Path_here_to_boost_Static_libraries}).
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

1. CGAL uses the shared Boost libraries. So, the libraries like "libboost_thread-vc100-mt-p-1_49.lib" are statically linked libraries.
2. It's because CMake (I used v2.8.9) can not read the name of Boost libraries correctly. When I changed the library names,
   **boost_thread-vc100-mt-p-1_49.dll** and **boost_thread-vc100-mt-p-1_49.lib** to **boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_49.dll** and **boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_49**, respectively, it fixed the problem.

Comment: For reference: Do NOT do this. The naming reflects how boost was compiled. So you need to set the correct options for the Find module or you will end up with problems of any kind (using debug versions for release, multi-threaded for single-threaded etc)