# find_package(Boost) error when BOOST_INCLUDEDIR & BOOST_LIBRARYDIR are different

Tags: boost, cmake

I'm trying to compile Boost as shared libraries and make them a dependency of my **cross platform** CMake project.

For that, I compiled boost for win32, x64 and linux where my boost folder structure looks like:

```
- boost_1_69_0/
  - boost/
  - stage/
    - win32
      - lib
    - x64
      - lib
    - linux
      - lib
```

Then I'm doing:

```
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/boost_1_69_0)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/boost_1_69_0/stage/win32)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
```

And getting:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Boost version: 1.69.0

Boost include path: C:/bla/SW/cmake-template/external/boost_1_69_0

Could not find the following Boost libraries:

        boost_filesystem
```

Is that a bug?

---

If I move the `lib` folder from inside `win32` to it's parent directory, i.e:

```
- boost_1_69_0/
  - boost/
  - stage/
    - lib
```

which is the default way boost's b2 build stuff, then it's all working. But then I can't hold different boost binaries for different platforms.

---

**EDIT**:

using `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` I found out my boost is compiled with Visual Studio v141 toolset while my project is using v140, and so `FindBoost` is looking for `boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-x64-1_69` and not `boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-x64-1_69`.

I guess the problem has shifted to either find a way to force searching for v141 or (better) use `--layout=system` and find a way to force it to always look for `boost_filesystem`. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Have a look at the library directory, is there a `boost_filesystem.dll` or `boost_filesystem.lib`?

Comment: @StanleyF. there's `boost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x32-1_69.dll` & `boost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x32-1_69.lib`

Comment: *Library directory* (what BOOST_LIBRARYDIR should be assigned to) is a directory which **immediately** contains libraries. In your case, this is a directory `external/boost_1_69_0/stage/win32/lib` (ended with **lib**). BTW, you may always check which **actual paths are searched** by `find_package(Boost)` with setting `Boost_DEBUG` variable to TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that CMake searches for boost libraries matching a certain naming scheme. Your libraries differ from that, since there are some options encoded within the filename. You have two options:

1. Compile boost again but this time with `--layout=system` flag when running the `b2` executable. This will create library files with standard names like `boost_filesystem.dll` and `boost_filesystem.lib`.
2. Give CMake some hints on how your library files are named, using the following [variables dedicated to boost variants](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindBoost.html) (since I don't have an equivalent system like yours, those are guesses, which you may have to adopt):

   - `Boost_ARCHITECTURE="-x32"`
   - `Boost_COMPILER="-vc141"`

Comment: Thanks, `Boost_COMPILER` did solve it! Is there a way to hind `FindBoost` to search for `--layout=system` on Windows as well? because it always looks to the default Windows layout.

Comment: Currently, `FindCmake` breaks for Windows if `layout=system` was used because it only looks for `boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-x64-1_69` and not for `boost_filesystem`. My question is whether it is possible to make it work, using a hidden flag or something like that.

Comment: @galah92 Actually, boost *is* looking for `boost_filesystem`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13281373/579698). So with `layout=system` everything should work out of the box. Without `layout=system` you need to specify the naming scheme as point 2 in my answer outlines.